# TryCatch which returns a value to my vector

Tags: r, exception, try-catch

So i'm currently writing some R code for a class.

```
library(pwr)
delta <- c(2.5, 5, 7.5,10)
v <- c(4,6,9,13)
size <- vector()


for (i in (v)){
  for (j in (delta)){
    tryCatch({
fRough <- sqrt(((1/i)*(j)^2)/(2*ucb2))
samplesize <- pwr.anova.test(k =i, f = fRough, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.9)
size <- c(size, (trunc((samplesize[["n"]]),0)+1)*i)
    }, error = function(e)(size <- c(size, i*2)))
  }
}
```

ucb2 is just some float value. I want to run through this loop but it gives an error when delta is 7.5 and 10. i want my code to output the value of (i*2) when it strikes an error. I tried using the error function but it didn't seem to work. Also, could someone suggest material where i could learn about function(e), function(cond), etc.  I am unable to find the answer on SO.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Try [this chapter](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Exceptions-Debugging.html) of Hadley's Advanced R to get started with exception handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to do the update of `size` inside the error function. Updating `size` to the return value of the error function will do the trick:

```
for (i in (v)){
  for (j in (delta)){
    size <- tryCatch({
      fRough <- sqrt(((1/i)*(j)^2)/(2*ucb2))
      samplesize <- pwr.anova.test(k =i, f = fRough, sig.level = 0.05, power = 0.9)
      c(size, (trunc((samplesize[["n"]]),0)+1)*i)
    },error = function(e) c(size, i*2))
  }
}
```